# ng2-translate: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined at TranslatePipe.transform

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngx-translate, ng2-translate, testbed

I use ng2-translate in my Angular 5 project and I am trying to create a unit test for one component.
I always import `TranslateModule.forRoot( *...* )` in my Tests and the tests will work using the translate pipe in my views.

In two cases though, the above error is thrown, during unit tests:
I don't see any difference to the other working tests.

> × should create (44ms)
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
>           at TranslatePipe.transform (webpack:///./node_modules/ng2-translate/src/translate.pipe.js?:74:75)
>           at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/MyComponent.ngfactory.js:127:70)
>           at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14951:21)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14065:14)

Any reasons why this could happen?
I don't use TranslateService, but I use the pipe in the template.
Did anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: I noticed that this error occured on any components where I was using the `translateParams` directive.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issue and I added to TranslateService mock class:

`public onLangChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 public onTranslationChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); 
 public onDefaultLangChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();`

Comment: still works with angular 9.0.7 and ngx-translate 11.0.1

Comment: Would be nice to see your entire mock service and how you import TranslateModule

Comment: Still running into this issue in 2020. Sad.

Comment: @CularBytes and others: In case someone stumbles over this again, I created an example: https://gist.github.com/alexanderfink/082d25aa4e0700d654e8612eb58d17b2

Comment: @GEMI 2022 salutes you

Comment: I started getting a `Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found.`

import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
to my imports fixed it all for me

Answer (score 1):

Let me extend @Agata's answer for **jasmine** users:

```
describe('MyTestComponent', () => {
  // ...
  
  const translateService = jasmine.createSpyObj<TranslateService>('translateService', ['instant', 'get']);
  const translateServiceMock = {
    currentLang: 'de',
    onLangChange: new EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>(),
    use: translateService.get,
    get: translateService.get.and.returnValue(of('')),
    onTranslationChange: new EventEmitter(),
    onDefaultLangChange: new EventEmitter()
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        // ...
      ],
      imports: [
        // ...
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
      ],
      providers: [
        // ...
        {provide: TranslateService, useValue: translateServiceMock}
      ]
      }).compileComponents();
  });
});
```